# How to configure startup.cs to take 2 connection string in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, database-connection

I have two connections string on appsettings.json. one contain user's Information and second one application Data. I want to ask how to configure startup.cs to take two connections string

```
{   "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }   },   "Data": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "RoomBookingDB": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=RoomBookingDB;Trusted_Connection=True;",
      "Intranet": "Server=bdServer;Database=Intranet; ..."
    }   } }
```

Comment: You should not register SqlConnections that way. Create SqlConnections in your data layer as needed. Don't create SqlConnections in your DI container.

Comment: Do you expect the framework to magically guess which connection to give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create new types to represent the settings needed for my various use cases. For example:

```
public class UserDatabaseSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDatabaseSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Create an instance of each of your settings classes and register them with the DI container.

This will allow your classes to demand the correct type of connection string...

```
public class UserRepository(UserDatabaseSettings settings)
{
    //use settings.ConnectionString here
}
```